# Getting background image fixed after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I need my website background became fixed after background image ends. Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/cEywp/1/

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Little explanation: I have header and after a 1280x1024 background image, marked as 100% width and height. I need when i scrolling down (when image ends) that image became fixed, not absolute anymore.

**EDIT**

I did it with scrollToFixed, just added to image. ;)

Comment: What is the problem? You link to a fiddle and thats it? I don't see any issues or code? Please read the FAQ on asking questions or review some of the higher voted questions to see how it's done.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin - http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/

Comment: @FlorianMargaine yup - see the fiddle. Has he asked a question yet? if you're looking for a design 'critique' you can also check out UX or CodeReview

Comment: @rlemon he has no javascript code.

Comment: I strongly suggest if the background image is the issue that you do not use a jQuery plugin to fix this. Good Old CSS is likely all you need.

Comment: I need it absolute, and when image ends - then fixed.

Answer (score 2):

you can write **position:fixed** instead of **position:absolute**.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cEywp/4/

It's better if you give image in `background` instead of `IMG.`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/cEywp/5/